# Why does changing my FRP implementation to be more reactive lag?

Tags: haskell, frp, threepenny-gui

I got a version of snake working with the `threepenny-gui` library, but I didn't like the fact that I was explicitly calling `newEvent` and `addStateUpdate` manually instead of defining the behavior completely based on events, e.g. this:

```
(updates, addUpdate) <- liftIO newEvent
managerB <- accumB initialManager updates

on UI.tick timer $ \_ -> addUpdate $ \manager -> manager'
```

compared to:

```
managerB <- accumB initialManager $
  UI.tick timer $> \manager -> manager'
```

IIUC the second is more idiomatic FRP, as it defines a behavior with the actual event instead of creating a proxy event to proxy updates through. But when I make this change, it causes one of two problems:

1. If I define `managerB` first (using RecursiveDo to access `timer`, which is defined below), nothing's rendered at all
2. If I move `managerB` to the end (using RecursiveDo to access `managerB` from the DOM elements), the initial movement when hitting an arrow key for the first time lags, and the frames render in a jerky fashion.

Am I doing something wrong? What's the idiomatic way I should structure these events/behaviors?

Code diff here: https://github.com/brandonchinn178/snake/compare/inline-event-handlers

Answer (score 0):

A not particularly pretty workaround for the jerkiness, which I tested on [the alternate branch in your repository](https://github.com/brandonchinn178/snake/blob/2b9d3adee8bd756d52bd5db3549cc7fa5d2672b2/src/Snake.hs), is, so to say, using both approaches at once: re-firing the tick event and using that instead of `UI.tick timer` to define `managerB`:

```
  (timeE, fireTime) <- liftIO newEvent
  on UI.tick timer $ \_ -> liftIO (fireTime ())

  let managerUpdateE =
        fmap concatenate . unions $
          [ timeE $> getNextManagerState
          --  Instead of: UI.tick timer $> getNextManagerState
          --  etc.
```

The issue appears to be that plugging `UI.tick timer` directly into the event network somehow gets in the way of Threepenny sending the JavaScript calls needed to update the UI in a timely way. The indirection in using `on` with `fireTime` (which, in particular, should mean `timeE` happens notionally after `UI.tick timer`) seems to skirt around the problem. A less intrusive workaround would be, instead of introducing `timeE`, explicitly calling [`flushCallBuffer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.9.1.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:flushCallBuffer) in a handler for `UI.tick timer`; in my tests, however, that reduced the jerkiness a lot but didn't eliminate it completely. (See also [threepenny-gui issue #191](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/threepenny-gui/issues/191) for possibly relevant background information.)

As for the delay on the first keystroke, it appears that can be eliminated by moving your invocation of `UI.start timer` to the very end of `gui`, after `managerB` and the rest of your event network is set up.

(On an additional note, it is probably a good idea to follow the recommendation of the [`Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Timer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.9.1.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Timer.html) docs and set `-threaded` in the `ghc-options` for compiling your executable, even if that doesn't seem to have an effect on the problem you describe here.)